# Unable to send email update upon insertion of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, email, smtp

I'm trying to allow my webapp to send an email update whenever a data is being inserted into the database like the codes i'll show below.

This is a btnAssign where it will update the relevant database table and column with data

```
protected void btnAssign_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                using (var connAdd = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {

                    String assign = ddlpid1.SelectedValue;

                    connAdd.Open();
                    var sql = "Update MemberReport Set assignto ='" + assign + "', caseprogress = 'ongoing' where memberreportID='" + lbmemberreportid.Text + "'";
                    using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
                    {
                        cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    sql = "Insert into PoliceReport(memberreportid) values('" + lbmemberreportid.Text + "')";
                    // sql = "Update PoliceAccount Set handle ='" + assign + "' where policeid ='" + ddlpid1.SelectedValue + "' OR '" + ddlpid2.SelectedValue + "'";
                    using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
                    {
                        cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    sql = "Update PoliceAccount Set handle ='" + lbmemberreportid.Text + "' where policeid ='" + ddlpid1.SelectedValue + "'";
                    // sql = "Update PoliceAccount Set handle ='" + assign + "' where policeid ='" + ddlpid1.SelectedValue + "' OR '" + ddlpid2.SelectedValue + "'";
                    using (var cmdAdd = new SqlCommand(sql, connAdd))
                    {
                        cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
}
```

The insertion / updating of database part is working fine. When i addthe smtp codes to send email by selecting a column, it didnt work.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader dr;

                //SqlConnection con = new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                //con.Open();
                // get the records matching the supplied username or email id.         
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from PoliceAccount where handle='" + lbmemberreportid.Text + "'", connAdd);


                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cmd.Dispose();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    dr.Read();


                    StringBuilder strBody = new StringBuilder();
                    //Passing emailid,username and generated unique code via querystring. For testing pass your localhost number and while making online pass your domain name instead of localhost path.
                    strBody.Append("<a>Please be notified that you've been assigned a case to handle. Please proceed to the scene with immediate effect.</a>");
                    // sbody.Append("&uCode=" + uniqueCode + "&uName=" + txtUserName.Text + ">Click here to change your password</a>");

                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("apr13mpsip@gmail.com", dr["email"].ToString(), "Case Pending", strBody.ToString());
                    //pasing the Gmail credentials to send the email
                    System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthenticaion = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("apr13mpsip@gmail.com", "Temasekpoly13");

                    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

                    mailclient.EnableSsl = true;
                    mailclient.Credentials = mailAuthenticaion;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mailclient.Send(mail);
                    dr.Close();
                    dr.Dispose();
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    //con.Close();
                    lbmemberreportid.Text = "";
                    ddllocation.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    ddlnumber.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    ddlpid1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    tbdetails.Text = "";
                    tbproperty.Text = "";
                    tbsuspect.Text = "";
                    ddlpid1.Visible = false;

                    LoadGrid();

                    lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblmsg.Text = "MemberReportID" + Session["memberreportid"] + "has been successfully assigned";

                }


                connAdd.Close();
                }
```

To make matter worse, the label where the message is suppose to appear did not appear. Which means after inserting the data, the code basically stop running. I added a txtFile in the [link](http://www.filedropper.com/admintask) here if the code i pasted above is confusing.

I really still cant figure out why does my email not run after inserting the data into the database.

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to determine how/why it's stopping?

Comment: Try Stepping to know exactly which line is giving error.

Comment: Hmm because this code works when i try to use it for my forget password function. But of course i have to change accordingly on my requirement. so basically the logic of the code is fine but just that after adding into another page then it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are reading `dr["email"].ToString()` but only select `assignto` column in your select sql statement . you can change the select sql statement to select both `assignto` and `email` columns .